# How to converting string to list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, file

I have a file and its consist of multiple lists like below

```
[234,343,234]
[23,45,34,5]
[354,45]
[]
[334,23]
```

I am trying to read line by line and append to a single list in python.

how to do it?

I tried so far>

```
with open("pos.txt","r") as filePos:
    pos_lists=filePos.read()
new_list=[]
for i in pos_lists.split("\n"):
    print(type(i)) #it is str i want it as list
    new_list.extend(i)

print(new_list)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a text file?

Comment: yes it's a textfile

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and where it failed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse list of numbers into list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009963/parse-list-of-numbers-into-list-in-python)

Comment: cool ast.literal_eval() works fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try these:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> with open(YOURTEXTFILE) as f:
...    final_list = [literal_eval(elem) for elem in f.readlines()]
>>> final_list
[[234, 343, 234], [23, 45, 34, 5], [354, 45], [], [334, 23]]
```

Or,

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> with open(YOURTEXTFILE) as f:
...    final_list = sum(map(literal_eval, s.readlines()), [])
>>> final_list
[234, 343, 234, 23, 45, 34, 5, 354, 45, 334, 23]
```

Whichever you want.

The same thing can be done with python built-in [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) however, it is not recommended to use `eval()` on untrusted code, instead use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which only works on very limited data types.
For more on this, see [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/5431791)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

```
>>> res = []
>>> with open('f.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...             res.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are assumed and intended to be *python literals* you can just `ast.literal_eval(line)`.

For safety you may want to assume they are *JSON values* instead, in which case `json.loads(line)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In case each line is a valid JSON array/object, you can use [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import jsonlines
r = []
with jsonlines.open('input.jsonl') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        for item in line:
            r.append(item)
print(r)
```

Output:

```
[234, 343, 234, 23, 45, 34, 5, 354, 45, 334, 23]
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use the split() method between the brackets you can give a symbol to split by.

between the brackets give the symbol you want to split it by.
Maybe like this:

```
txt = "[234,343,234]/[23,45,34,5]/[354,45]/[]/[334,23]"        
x = txt.split("/")
```